# Restrict which branches can be tagged

Tags: gerrit

I have allowed a certain usergroup to create branches under a namespace; refs/heads/patch/*.

When a new branch has been created here, the same users should have permission to push an annotated tag that resides on that branch, but not elsewhere.

How can this be accomplished?

My initial (bad) idea was to give this group the "push annotatad tag" permission for /refs/tags/patch/*. But of course this only creates the restriction that tags must be named "patch/tag_name" and does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible out of the box, but I think you can write a [ref-update hook](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/config-hooks.html#_ref_update) to enforce such a policy. I'm assuming the hook is called for all ref updates, including tags, but I'm not completely sure of that.

Before starting, make sure you've figured out the semantics for how to evaluate a tag. Since neither tags nor commits belong to or reside on a branch you'll have to use a more elaborate condition. Perhaps: "For this group of users, allow the tag if the commit it points to is reachable from one or more refs matching refs/heads/patch/* but only if it's also not reachable from any other refs"? I think that's a good starting point, but it will block tags that point to commits "on" patch branches if the patch branch has been merged to, say, master. This may or may not be acceptable in your case.